# What is the difference between between context.watch and context.read in flutter_bloc?

Tags: android, flutter, mobile, flutter-bloc, flutter-cubit

I just learn about a cubit in a flutter. I learn in the tutorial video, so in that video, the mentor made a login page that contains an email and password text field and one login button. In that video, the mentor still uses the old version of flutter_bloc. There is a warning when I follow one of the code lines

```
child: ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () {
    context.watch<AuthCubit>().signIn(
     _emailController.text,
     _passwordController.text);
}
```

that code is written inside the onPressed function button.
it says that `context.bloc` is deprecated. When I try to run the app it returns an error because the flutter_bloc's version I used has not supported null safety so I upgrade it to the current version (7.3.1) and I found this in version 6.1.0 changelog (you can see it in [flutter_bloc change log](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc/changelog) )

```
deprecated: context.bloc in favor of context.read and context.watch
```

Because I don't know the difference I just change `context.bloc` to `context.watch` then I run the app again and it returns another error

```
Tried to listen to a value exposed with a provider, from outside of the widget tree.

This is likely caused by an event handler (like a button's onPressed) that called
Provider.of without passing `listen: false`.

To fix, write:
Provider.of<AuthCubit>(context, listen: false);

It is unsupported because may pointlessly rebuild the widget associated to the
the event handler, when the widget tree doesn't care about the value.
...
```

And when I change it to `context.read` it works. I am wondering about the difference between them

Answer (score 3):

`context.watch<T>()` listens to changes on T

`context.read<T>()` returns T without listening to it

You were calling

```
context.watch<AuthCubit>().signIn(
     _emailController.text,
     _passwordController.text);
```

in the `ElevatedButton's` `onPressed()` and thereby listening to `AuthCubit` exposed with provider, from outside of the widget tree. When you change it to use `context.read<AuthCubit>` you return `AuthCubit` without listening to it from outside the widget tree.

Comment: Thanks man for the answer, but i still have some questions. What is meant by 'outside widget tree'? is it the widget outside BlocProvider or what?

Comment: @AlunParanggi This issue from the provider package discusses what 'outside widget tree' means and why you should avoid listening outside your widget tree